# Creating a column of random numbers from a distribution with mean and std from other columns using python

Tags: python, function, numpy, random

I would like to be able to basically pass a column into the `np.random.normal()` function.

I have the following;

```
def calc_z(w,S,a1,a2,yt1,yt2):

    mu = w * S
    print 'Mu' , mu
    sigma = mt.sqrt(0.5)
    z = np.array(np.random.normal(mu,sigma))
    u = [a1,a2,z]
    yt = [yt1,yt2,1]
    thetaset = np.random.rand(len(u))
    m = [i for i in range(len(u))]

    max_iter = 30

#Calculate E-step
    for i in range(max_iter):

        print 'Iteration:', i
        print 'z:', z
        print 'thetaset', thetaset

        devLz = eq6(var,w,S,z,yt,u,thetaset,m)
        dev2Lz2 = eq9(var,thetaset,u)

#Calculate M-Step
        z = z - (devLz / dev2Lz2)
        w = lambdaw * z

        for i in range(len(thetaset)):

            devLTheta = eq7(yt,u,thetaset,lambdatheta)
            dev2LTheta2 = eq10(thetaset,u,lambdatheta)           

            thetaset = thetaset - (devLTheta / dev2LTheta2)

    return float(z)

calc_z_udf = udf(calc_z,FloatType())

data.show()

data = data.withColumn('z', calc_z(data['w'],data['Org_Depth_Diff_S'],data['proximity_rank_a1'],data['cotravel_count_a2'],data['cotravel_yt1'],data['proximity_yt2']))
```

But when I pass `S` in, the `np.random.normal` function doesn't like being passed a column  and gives me the following error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/taylorr2/PySparkLatent3.py", line 125, in <module>
    data = data.withColumn('z', calc_z(data['w'],data['Org_Depth_Diff_S'],data['proximity_rank_a1'],data['cotravel_count_a2'],data['cotravel_yt1'],data['proximity_yt2']))
  File "/home/taylorr2/PySparkLatent3.py", line 90, in calc_z
    z = np.array(np.random.normal(mu,sigma))
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1282, in mtrand.RandomState.normal (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:6920)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I am trying to think of a way to get this function to accept this value or do this a different way.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using it like this: `thetaset = np.random.rand(size=len(u))`

Comment: That's great for a general random number. I want the mean of the distribution from which the random number is taken to be based on some value that I can pass in however.

Comment: OK, then use also the `loc` statement:
`thetaset = np.random.rand(loc=S,size=len(u))` which shifts the mean to S. See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) for all options.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You could try `mu = np.concatenate(mu)` to make it a flat array before passing it into the `np.random.normal`. See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) for reference. The input has to be shaped like a multi dimensional array, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Sorry I am having the issue with calculating `z`. I have looked at the documentation you suggested but again, when I pass in `mu` and `sigma` to `z=np.random.normal(loc=mu,scale=sigma)` I get the same error as I did initially. I also tried `mu = np.concatenate(mu)` but that told me `TypeError: object of type 'Column' has no len()`

Comment: What are the types of the objects that you are passing to `np.random.normal`?  That is, what are `type(mu)` and `type(sigma)`?  Also, if the type is `numpy.ndarray`, what is the dtype of the array?  That is, what are `mu.dtype` and `sigma.dtype`?  (The dtype attribute won't work if the objects are, say, python floats or lists.)

Comment: `type(mu)` is `<class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>` and `type(sigma)` is `<type 'float'>`

Comment: You'll probably have to convert `mu` to a numpy array of floats or a Python list of floats.  It looks like `np.random.normal` is unable to handle that `Column` object.